# Build opencv-mobile

Tags: android, c++, kotlin, opencv, cmake

I use the short version for open cv from the link [text](https://github.com/nihui/opencv-mobile.git)

I want to use it instead of the open cv homepage release because it's much lighter and provides all the functionality I need. But when I try to use it, it always shows an error

```
cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\23.2.8568313\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe --target=aarch64-none-linux-android24 --gcc-toolchain=C:/Users/ADMIN/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.2.8568313/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=C:/Users/ADMIN/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.2.8568313/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -fPIC -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -fno-limit-debug-info  -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id=sha1 -Wl,--no-rosegment -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -shared -Wl,-soname,libipainted.so -o D:\imagefilter\ipainted\app\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\p39g4432\obj\arm64-v8a\libipainted.so CMakeFiles/ipainted.dir/native-lib.cpp.o  -ljnigraphics  D:/imagefilter/ipainted/app/src/main/cpp/opencv-mobile-4.6.0-android/sdk/native/staticlibs/arm64-v8a/libopencv_core.a  D:/imagefilter/ipainted/app/src/main/cpp/opencv-mobile-4.6.0-android/sdk/native/staticlibs/arm64-v8a/libopencv_imgproc.a  C:/Users/ADMIN/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.2.8568313/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/24/liblog.so  D:/imagefilter/ipainted/app/src/main/cpp/opencv-mobile-4.6.0-android/sdk/native/staticlibs/arm64-v8a/libopencv_core.a  -ldl  -lm  -llog  -latomic -lm && cd ."

ld: error: undefined symbol: __kmpc_global_thread_num
>>> referenced by parallel.cpp
>>>               parallel.cpp.o:(cv::parallel_for_(cv::Range const&, cv::ParallelLoopBody const&, double)) in archive D:/imagefilter/ipainted/app/src/main/cpp/opencv-mobile-4.6.0-android/sdk/native/staticlibs/arm64-v8a/libopencv_core.a
```

Does anyone know how to fix this please help me

this is how i do it,here is the code in my build.gradle file

```
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path file('src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt')
            version '3.22.1'
        }
    }

    android {
        ndkVersion "23.2.8568313"
    }
```

here is the cmakelist code i made

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22.1)

project("ipainted")

set(OpenCV_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/opencv-mobile-4.6.0-android/sdk/native/jni)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED core imgproc)

add_library(
        ipainted
        SHARED
        native-lib.cpp)

find_library(
        log-lib
        log)


target_link_libraries(
        ipainted
        jnigraphics
        ${OpenCV_LIBS}
        ${log-lib})
```

here is the c++ code i make the test

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_fftools_ipainted_MainActivity_bitmapToGray(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jobject bitmap) {
    AndroidBitmapInfo bitmapInfo;
    AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bitmap, &bitmapInfo);

    void* pixels;
    AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmap, &pixels);

    cv::Mat mat(bitmapInfo.height, bitmapInfo.width, CV_8UC4, pixels);

    cv::Mat grayMat;
    cv::cvtColor(mat, grayMat, cv::COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);

    AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmap);
}
```